# Read file in Jenkins and add lines to environment varibles

Tags: unix, jenkins

I am pretty new to jenkins and UNIX commands. How can I via shell command read txt file line by line and add it to environment variables?
My goal is to read generated text file and then send its content via mail, for that I've downloaded mail plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally i dont think it is the best way to read it with shell and then send it with jenkins. I would rather do some small app which would read it and then send it, but it depends on what is really your objective.

But ok, you can do it like this:
1. either execute a shell script like this

```
#!/bin/ksh
file="somePropertyFile.properties"
counter=1

while IFS= read line
do
    # display $line 
    echo "$line" 
    counter=`expr $counter + 1`
    # either export it 
    # export $counter=$line
    # or send it straight trough mail "sendmail"
    mail -s $line you@youremailid.com

done <"$file"
```

2. and/or you can use https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin

Hope it helps